# Under Leads tab, how do I change Default View to display only leads with Status Field "Open" and "Closed"?

Tags: visualforce, list-view, custom, tab

When I click on the Leads Tab, an overview page is displayed. I'd like the default list on the Leads tab overview page to display only leads that have a value of "open" and "Closed" in the Status field.
any body please share me visualforce custom tab code or any suggestions?

Comment: Yes i am also searching for this. when i click content object,the records display  view will show with different tabs and columns. i need to show like this for all objects. if anybody knows please tell me. it is very useful for us....

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom view which is provided on top of the list beside the drop down which shows the current view. There you can provide conditions/filters that must be satisfied by the record in order to appear in the view you are creating.[image: if you see in the below image you can see the drop down list 'All Open Leads' which shows current view, just click on create new view link and there you can specify in condition like only closed and open]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i need under leads tab status field Values(open and closed) only. so how do i remove/hide default buttons(New lead, changestatus, change owner, add to campaign) or entire default view page.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you
[Default List view](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hH5aAAE)